# Searching android devices using WiFi app

Tags: android

I am working on a WiFi based app, I have a program with me and i also added permissions still it is not giving response.

How to test it or emulate it once it does?

I have added this permission block:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Here is my source:

```
 package org.example.WiFi;
 import java.util.List;
 import android.app.Activity; 
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; 
 import android.content.Context; 
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.net.wifi.ScanResult; 
 import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class WiFiActivity extends Activity {
    TextView mainText;

    WifiManager mainWifi;

    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;

    List<ScanResult> wifiList;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.search);

    mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);


    receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();

    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    mainWifi.startScan();

    mainText.setText("\nStarting Scan...\n");

}
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

            mainWifi.startScan();

            mainText.setText("Starting Scan");

            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);

    }
    protected void onPause() {

            unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);

            super.onPause();

    }

    protected void onResume() {

            registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new 

    IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

            super.onResume();

    }
     ass WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

                    sb = new StringBuilder();

                    wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();

            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){

                    sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");

                    sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());

                    sb.append("\n");

            }
            mainText.setText(sb);

            }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Please edit and reformat that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your title says "Searching android devices using WiFi app". On Android you can only search Wifi access points, not devices.

Wifi devices can be potentially discovered in Wifi ad hoc mode, which is not supported on Android: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82